# Objective-C put string at location of another string

Tags: objective-c, string, nsstring, substring

I wan't to "know" how to put a string at a location in another string. I already know because I figured out another way to do this. But I wan't to know the real way, does it even exist?

I'm also asking this question for future questions on *how to put this string at a location in another string* the "false" way (in case it can't be done the real way)

What I mean about putting a (sub)string at a location of string is for example to put

this string:@"Hello" at location:5 inString:@"123456789"

I want the results to be:@"12345Hello6789"
Can this be done the real way? something like this fake code:

```
[str stringByPuttingString:@"s" atLocation:5];//this code does not exist
```

I figured out other ways to get this done, can we get it to shorter code?

```
-(NSString *)putString:(NSString *)str atLocation:(int)location ofString:(NSString *)mainString {
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(location, 0);
    return [mainString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:str];
}
```

and

```
-(NSString *)putString:(NSString *)str atLocation:(int)location ofString:(NSString *)mainString {
    NSString *first = [mainString substringToIndex:location];
NSString *last = [mainString substringFromIndex:location];
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", first, str, last];
}
```

The first one feels best, any other ideas or real ideas?

Jonathan, 
in future cases of this "problem".

Comment: Look at `NSMutableString`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just use an `NSMutableString`?

```
NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"123456789"];

[string insertString:@"Hello" atIndex:5];

NSLog(@"%@", string);
```

Outputs:

```
12345Hello6789
```

Comment: Why are you creating the mutable string from a C string? You can do `string = `[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"123456789"]` or `string = [@"123456789" mutableString]`.

Comment: You're right, Im so used to seeing `stringWithString` telling me its redundant that I forgot to use it for this case. Edited the answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use NSMutableString to accomplish this task. Specifically, see the reference to the insertString:atIndex: method which will do exactly what you want, i.e. insert a string into another string at a specified location. [API LINK](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutablestring_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/insertString%3aatIndex%3a)

Answer (score 1):

you can implement this by using NSMutableString method **insertString:atIndex:**

Inserts into the receiver the characters of a given string at a given location.

```
- (void)insertString:(NSString *)aString atIndex:(NSUInteger)anIndex
```

**Parameters**

**aString**
    The string to insert into the receiver. aString must not be nil.

**anIndex**
    The location at which aString is inserted. The location must not exceed the bounds of the receiver.

Taken from [apple developer classes ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutablestring_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/insertString%3aatIndex%3a)